# How to find an NSString inside another NSString?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I am a real beginner here and this is my first post ever so bear with me...  I have an AddressBook that contains an array of AddressCards.  'book' is an NSMutableArray.  I want to look up a string and have it return an array of matches from the AddressBook.  For example, a search for 'fr' returns 'freddy', 'frank', 'franklin'.  What is my problem here?  Thanks for the help.

```
- (NSMutableArray *)lookup:(NSString *)theName {
    NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    AddressCard *nextCard;
    for(nextCard in book) {
        if ([nextCard.name rangeOfString:theName].location != NSNotFound) {
             [newArray addObject:nextCard];
        }
    } 
    if (nextCard) {
        return newArray;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: You never initialize `newArray`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
- (NSArray *)lookup:(NSString *)theName {
    NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(AddressCard *card in book) {
        if ([card.name rangeOfString:theName].location != NSNotFound) {
             [newArray addObject:card];
        }
    } 

    return [newArray count] ? [newArray copy] : nil;
}
```

You can also use `-filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`

```
- (NSArray *)lookup:(NSString *)theName {
   NSArray *filteredCardsMatchingName = [books filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@", theName]];
   return [filteredCardsMatchingName count] ? filteredCardsMatchingName : nil;
}
```